# choosing one pair randomly from repeated pairs

Tags: r, sampling

I have two vectors, in my case all states in the US, and another vector, which indicates the states that it borders. States in vector 1 repeat for each state it borders. For instance, there would be 3 observations for California: California-Nevada; California-Oregon; California-Arizona.

For each state, I would like to randomly choose one of these dyads and create a new dataset. Let's say the original data set was 300 x 2. The new dataset would be 50x2. Here is an example dataset.

```
state <- sample(state.abb,size=300,replace=T)
neighbor <- sample(state.abb,size=300,replace=T)
data <- data.frame(state,neighbor)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (of course) any number of ways to do this.  The approach I apply here uses `data.table` and does what is desired in a single line of code that is readable if you are familiar with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
result <- data.table(data)[,.SD[sample(1:.N,1),],by="state",]
```

In short, we convert data into a data.table.  Using the nomenclature `data.table(data)[i,j]`...

We are processing data by subsets of each unique value for state (the `by` argument), as if we used `state==` for each unique value of `state` in position of the argument `i` (row selection).

The `j` argument (results) provides the output from each subset.  Here we want a random row from each subset of data.  Each individual subset is internally referred to as .SD in the position of j.  So, we can just randomly sample a row from that subset (`[sample(1:.N,1),]`) in the `i` (row selection arguement) where `.N` is internally defined for a data.table (in this case .SD, because this is a bracketed selection from .SD) as the number of rows in that data.table.

Comment: P.S. If you aren't already familiar with data.table you should be made aware that result is a data.table and won't behave quite like a data.frame, but you can just do `new.result <- data.frame(result)` and push the data.table back into a data.frame if you so desire.